# Json schema validation for binary tree logic operations

Tags: json, validation, logical-operators, boolean-logic, jsonschema

This goes partly toward data validation but I'm struggling if it can be done with json schema validation that would suite better for my needs. My input is:

```
(1 or (1 and 0)) => true
```

which becomes a json object:

```
[1, [1, 0]]
```

So validation should give no errors, but currently my schema can't handle OR case correctly between nested data.

```
{
  "allOf": [
    {"$ref": "#/definitions/_items"},
    {
      "allOf": [
        {"$ref": "#/definitions/_or"},
        {
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/_and"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "_items": {
      "minItems": 1,
      "maxItems": 2,
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          {"enum": [1,0]},
          {"$ref": "#/definitions/_items"}
        ]
      }
    },
    "_or": {
      "not": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "not": {
            "anyOf": [
              {"enum": [1]},
              {"$ref": "#/definitions/_items"}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "_and": {
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          {"enum": [1]},
          {"$ref": "#/definitions/_items"}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Validating next data against the schema:

```
[1,0] is valid, ok
[1,1] is valid, ok
[0,1] is valid, ok
[0,0] not valid, ok
[[1,1],1] valid, ok
[[1,1],0] valid, ok
```

but:

```
[[1,0],1] not valid, not ok!
[[0,0],1] not valid, not ok!
```

because both have 1 on OR operator, so left side should not matter if is just meets _items definition.

So my question is how should I change the schema so that anyOf the OR operator sides is enought for valid input?

More examples requested By @esp:

My input examples by logical expression and corresponding json data:

```
1 or (1 and 0)) => [1, [1, 0]] => true
1 or (0 and 1)) => [1, [0, 1]] => true
1 or (1 and 1)) => [1, [0, 0]] => true
1 or (0 and 0)) => [1, [0, 0]] => true
1 or (1)) => [1, [1]] => true
1 or (0)) => [1, [0]] => true
1 or 1 => [1, 1 => true
1 or 0 => [1, 0] => true
0 or 1 => [0, 1] => true
0 or 0 => [0, 0] => false
```

I'm giving also few nested examples on the left side, but not all, because combinations gets quickly wild:

```
(1 and 0) or (1 and 0)) => [[1, 0], [1, 0]] => false
(0 and 0) or (0 and o)) => [[0, 0], [0, 0]] => false
(1 and 1) or (1 and 0)) => [[1, 1], [1, 0]] => true
(1 and 0) or (1 and 1)) => [[1, 0], [1, 1]] => true
(1 and 1) or (1 and 1)) => [[1, 1], [1, 1]] => true
```

Comment: can you define all possible inputs and expected outputs? Some of your examples don't match x or (y and z) pattern.

Comment: Also there seems to be two problems - whether expression matches the pattern and whether it's true, so you probably need two schemas rather then one, otherwise how you are going to differentiate between not matching pattern and false?

Comment: @esp : Added examples. So input can be: ´[p] or [q] or [p, q] or [p, [q]] or [[p], q] or [[p],[q]]´, left and right side of the binary item can be a number 1,0 or a set containing at least one similar item, but maximum of two. This should be already done with _items definition.

Answer (score 1):

Using draft-06 keywords "contains" (validates that array contains at least one item matching schema) and "const" (same as "enum" with one allowed value):

```
{
  "contains": { "$ref": "#/definitions/one" },
  "definitions": {
    "one": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "const": 1 },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/all" }
      ]
    },
    "all": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/one" }
    }
  }
}
```

As I wrote in comment, this schema only evaluates your boolean logic, it does not validate that the tree is correct. Also it evaluates ANDs on all levels but the first.

Without draft-06 keywords you can:

```
{
  "not": { "items": { "not": { "$ref": "#/definitions/one" } } },
  "definitions": {
    "one": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "enum": [1] },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/all" }
      ]
    },
    "all": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/one" }
    }
  }
}
```

To validate that the tree structure is valid you need another simple schema:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "minItems": 1,
  "maxItems": 2,
  "items": {
    "anyOf": [
      { "enum": [0, 1] },
      { "$ref": "#" }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can join these two schemas in one with "allOf", but then you won't see the difference between the tree with invalid structure and the tree that evaluates to false.

Comment: So this means it is not possible to get validation working in a way that both nested structure and enum parts are validated seamingly at the same time?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You can merge two schemas in one if that's what you mean

Comment: I try to rephrase that better later. I suspect my original question wasn't too clear at first hand.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are fairly few permutations, enumerating the possible states makes the schema simpler and easier to read.

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "minItems": 1,
  "maxItems": 2,
  "items": {
    "anyOf": [
      { "enum": [0, 1] },
      { "enum": [[0], [1]] },
      { "enum": [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]] }
    ]
  },
  "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/_or" }]
  "definitions": {
    "_or": {
      "not": {
        "items": {
          "not": { "$ref": "#/definitions/_and" }
        }
      }
    },
    "_and": { "enum": [1, [1], [1, 1]] }
  }
}
```

Comment: Right. Binary tree Im struggling with, have unlimited nested branches, which is part of the problem. I think it requires recursive validation. But more strictly speaking of my question, your answer seems to work.

Comment: @MarkokraM It's still not clear, if it is recursive tree, are there ORs on levels but the last, and only the last has AND or are there ANDs on all levels but the first.

Comment: Correct. Operators for different binary nodes should be defined by nested allOf parts starting from the root as on my example there are two levels now, but could be any.